# How can I transpose a quote in Lilypond?

Tags: lilypond

I'm transcribing a piece that has a section
where one instrument doubles another an octave lower.
I'd expect something like this short example to work:

```
oboe = \relative c' {
  \clef treble
  | c g a b | c e d c |
}
\addQuote "oboe" { \oboe }

bassoon = \relative c {
  \clef bass
  | e d c c |
  | \transpose c' c { \quoteDuring #"oboe" { s1 } } |
}

\new Staff \with { instrumentName = #"Oboe" } \oboe
\new Staff \with { instrumentName = #"Bassoon" } \bassoon
```

However, the `\transpose` command seems to be ignored, and the output is:

[image]

The desired output is:

[image]

How can I tell Lilypond to move the quote down an octave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now realized that I put the transposition in the wrong place.
The `\transpose` command was only applying to the contents of the `\quoteDuring`
(i.e. `s1`),
not the quoted music itself.

I found [this link](http://lilypond.1069038.n5.nabble.com/quoteDuring-with-octave-transposition-td4374.html),
which gave me the very simple idea of creating multiple quotes:

```
oboe = \relative c' {
  \clef treble
  | c g a b | c e d c |
}
\addQuote "oboe"  { \oboe }
\addQuote "oboe," { \transpose c' c \oboe }

bassoon = \relative c {
  \clef bass
  | e d c c |
  | \quoteDuring #"oboe," { s1 } |
}

\new Staff \with { instrumentName = #"Oboe" } \oboe
\new Staff \with { instrumentName = #"Bassoon" } \bassoon
```

This works as intended.